# Local host :3000 (React JS) can't be reached

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-development-server

Just started working in React JS ... I made changes in App.js file after which whenever I try to run the local host:3000 (React JS local server) ... It is showing it can't be reached

Comment: Asking the obvious, is the server started by running `npm start`?

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of stackoverfow before you start asking the questions

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet to the port? Try:

```
telnet localhost 3000
```

That should tell you if the ports unavailable at the TCP level, or whether something's going on at the HTTP level.

Ping might not work if ICMP is disabled, which could be completely unrelated to your issue.

Also, try looking in your hosts file for any redirections:

c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: type in your terminal: netstat -an |find /i “listening” to find out which ports are listening.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, I was working on multiple react projects. Whenever I switched the project, I cleared my browser cache/cookies and it started working for me seamlessly.